# Vertical pane icon in Outlook Web App (OWA) is no more showing

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-app, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an outlook add-in targeting OWA, Outlook 2016 for Mac & Windows. Few month back when I started and testing the application, the small icon to activate the add-in was showing. But the icon is no more showing with same manifest and all setting same. Please refer the screenshot.[image: No icon for my add-in but for Evernote]

Is this part of any update from Microsoft? How I can fix it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi, you sure the target icon url pointed by the manifest is correct and accessible ?

Comment: yes it is accessible and defined under <Resources> <bt:Images>. I just check again

Comment: It is visible from the "outside" can you post the img link url here ?

Comment: Also you sure you are not messing up with multiple manifests ? I have multiple manifests for the same addin, debuging mode local with url like `https://localhost:XXX`, one preprod `https://debug.myawesomeapp.com` and prod `https://app.myawesomeapp.com`. Of course you need to use different GUIDS for AppId

Comment: Is your SSL certificate valid and trusted? Please check the image sizes according of specification of "Resources" section of the manifest. Did you add recently "VersionOverridesV1_1" section to support mobile devices? If so check image sizes for this section, they are different with "VersionOverridesV1_0" and main section.

Comment: I got the issue. I was missing the `<IconUrl .../>` element.

An additional note here, `<IconUrl .../>` should be **above** `<HighResolutionIconUrl ../>` element otherwise manifest does not pass the validation.

Answer (score 1):

OWA uses the IconUrl in the section above version overrides because it uses the addin icon while Outlook desktop clients use the individual  control icon. It looks like you found this but I just wanted to add this answer so it is more visible.

An additional note here, `<IconUrl .../>` should be **above** `<HighResolutionIconUrl ../>` element otherwise manifest does not pass the validation.